# PHP Stripe get balance

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway with PHP. I need to retrieve the balance amount available in my account to initiate a transfer. Please describe pending and available amount given below in the API response. Under what condition the available amount turns negative. I am using in test mode.

```
Stripe_Balance::retrieve();

{
  "pending": [
    {
      "amount": 37353,
      "currency": "usd"
    }
  ],
  "available": [
    {
      "amount": -13725,
      "currency": "usd"
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "object": "balance"
}
```

Comment: **Done any refunds?** And better ask them on Twitter. They reply quite quickly.